# How to listen to two RabbitMQ queues with spring-cloud-stream

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I've got a working application that listens to a single RabbitMQ queue.

However, when I add another bean that consumes messages and try to bind that to another queue, neither of the queues are created in RabbitMQ and when creating them manually no messages are consumed from these queues.

Small kotlin project I created to demonstrate the issue:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class SpringCloudStreamTwoRabbitConsumersApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SpringCloudStreamTwoRabbitConsumersApplication>(*args)
}
```

```
package com.example.springcloudstreamtworabbitconsumers

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.messaging.Message
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import java.util.function.Consumer

@Component
class Listener1Config {

    @Bean
    fun listener1(): Consumer<Message<String>> {
        return Consumer { input -> println(input) }
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.springcloudstreamtworabbitconsumers

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.messaging.Message
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import java.util.function.Consumer

@Component
class Listener2Config {

    @Bean
    fun listener2(): Consumer<Message<String>> {
        return Consumer { input -> println(input) }
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
# Rabbit properties
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest

# Listener 1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.listener1-in-0.destination=exchange1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.listener1-in-0.group=exchange1-queue
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.listener1-in-0.consumer.queueNameGroupOnly=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.listener1-in-0.consumer.binding-routing-key-delimiter=,
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.listener1-in-0.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=binding.key.1,binding.key.1.1
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.listener1-in-0.consumer.exchangeType=topic
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.listener1-in-0.consumer.autoBindDlq=true

# Listener 2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.listener2-in-0.destination=exchange2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.listener2-in-0.group=exchange2-queue
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.listener2-in-0.consumer.queueNameGroupOnly=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.listener2-in-0.consumer.binding-routing-key-delimiter=,
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.listener2-in-0.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=binding.key.2,binding.key.2.1
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.listener2-in-0.consumer.exchangeType=topic
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.listener2-in-0.consumer.autoBindDlq=true
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.30"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.30"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2020.0.1"

dependencies {
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I comment out one of the listener beans the other one works as expected. However with both beans active, no queue is created in RabbitMQ, nor are messages read from the queues if I create them manually and send messages to the exchange.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework can only detect a single function. When you have multiple, you need to specify:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=listener1;listener2
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function

> In the event you only have single bean of type `java.util.function.[Supplier/Function/Consumer]`, you can skip the `spring.cloud.function.definition` property, since such functional bean will be auto-discovered. However, it is considered best practice to use such property to avoid any confusion.